# Теряется фокус кнопки

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

При наведении на кнопку теряется фокус при положении курсора в пустом месте между границей кнопки и надписью кнопки.

Подсветка при наведении (зелёным цветом)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь курсор между + и границей кнопки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<Button x:Name="button_asave_plus" Content="+" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="262,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20" 
    Style="{DynamicResource ButtonStyle}"/>
```

Стиль:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="#444444" />-->

        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFF" />
        <!--<Setter Property="Button.Background" Value="#00FF00" />-->
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#00FF00" />

        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#555555"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>
        <!--<Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>-->
        <!--<Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="23"/>
            <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="75"/>-->
        <Setter Property="Template" >
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Border
          x:Name="Border"
          CornerRadius="0"
          BorderThickness="1"
          >
                        <ContentPresenter
            Margin="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            RecognizesAccessKey="True"

                            />


                    </Border>


                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>


                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#555555" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#90EE90" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="false">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#555555" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#CCCCCC" />

                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted" Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#555555" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#CCCCCC" />

                        </Trigger>
                        <!--Цвет при наведении мыши -->
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <!--<Setter TargetName="Button.Static.Background"  Property="Background" Value="#000F00" />-->
                            <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#90EE90" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#90EE90" />
                            <!--<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,1,1"/>-->
                        </Trigger>
                        <!--Цвет при нажатии мыши-->
                        <!--<Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="true">
                                -->
                        <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="#000000" />-->
                        <!--
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#90EE90" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#90EE90" />
                            </Trigger>-->
                        <!--<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#555555" />
                            </Trigger>-->
                        <!--<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#555555" />
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#90EE90" />
                            </Trigger>-->
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Событие `MouseMove` (и соответственно свойство `IsMouseOver`) не срабатывает на элементах без фона (`Brackground`), а по умолчанию у элемента `Border` его нет (он равен `null`).

```xml
...
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <!-- Привязываем фон Border к фону стиля -->
    <Border x:Name="Border"
            CornerRadius="0"
            BorderThickness="1"
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
        <ContentPresenter
...
```